# How To Do Multiple Hover On List

Tags: html, css

Alright so i wanted to know how i can select multiple items on hover for example when i hover on list **a** Highlight **a** and on list **b**, give that list box shadow. ive tried to code it but for some reason im not able to do the multiple hover effect.

CSS Code:

```
#a:hover ~ #b {
    background: #ccc
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div><ul id="a"><li>Div A</li></ul></div>
<div>random elements</div>
<div>random elements</div>
<div>random elements</div>
<div><ul id="b"><li>Div B</li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Better use jquery for that. :)

Comment: I Would But I Only Know Html Css Mysql And Php Lol

Comment: Do you want to highlight BOTH tags at the same time when only ONE is hovered over?

Comment: @n00b Yea And Vice Versa If Also Possible?

Comment: please check http://jsfiddle.net/yB9p2/1/

Comment: @EugineJoseph Okay so if i wanna give a design to it use the part were it says css??

Comment: if you want to change background of #a or #b, change in jquery too.. :)

Comment: @EugineJoseph what do you mean too? if i make a change in the css part i also have to make a change in the jquery css also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the jquery I have used

```
$('#a').hover(function(){
  $('#a').css('background','#ccc');
  $('#b').css('background','#ccc');
}, function(){
  $('#a').css('background','#fff');  // Background of #a by default 
  $('#b').css('background','#fff');  // Background of #b by default 
})

$('#b').hover(function(){
  $('#a').css('background','#ccc');
  $('#b').css('background','#ccc');
}, function(){
  $('#a').css('background','#fff');  // Background of #a by default 
  $('#b').css('background','#fff');  // Background of #b by default 
})
```

If you are changing the background of #a or #b, 
specify the color to the places I had mentioned too. Simple :)

Comment: i guess if i dont find the right answer using html css i will select your answer for most useful thanks btw

Comment: Yeah Yours Is The Best Answer Lol Thanks Man Good Lookin

Comment: Lets expect for some more modifications in css. with use of parent and more.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The tilde `~` is for siblings.

But `#b` is not a sibling for `#a`

Change the id and it will work : (http://jsbin.com/AxUzOX/1/edit)

```
<div id="a">
    <ul >
        <li>Div A</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    random elements
</div>
<div>
    random elements
</div>
<div>
    random elements
</div>
<div id="b">
    <ul >
        <li>Div B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the jquery solution if you want http://jsbin.com/AxUzOX/4/edit

Comment: Your code is Correct but I Was actually Trying to not use the outter div for that i wanna use the ul for the id

Comment: that's fine. but you wont be able to use `~`. cuz tjey are not siblings.

Comment: what would i have to use for the siblings?

Comment: @TonyThinkk give some class name or id name to that parent div. it is not possible without it.

Comment: @Mr_Green what do you mean like class="a" ?

Comment: i dont understand jquery but since that works i guess i have a new book to read lol but thanks @RoyiNamir other than your answer im still going to try to come up with an answer using html css because i wanna give div (a) a design

Answer (score 0):

You should actually mention some class name or id name to the parent div which has the ul `#a` but as you don't want to assign it, you can use `:first-child` as shown below:

```
#a:hover {
    background: #ccc
}

div:first-child:hover ~ div>ul#b{
    color: red;
}
```

As you can see, I am hovering on the first child of div instead of ul because hovering on ul is same as hovering on parent div in your case.

I have did this way because there is no parent selector available in css not even in css3/css4.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/yB9p2/2/)

### Updated

for your previous sibling selector issue, use jquery

```
$('#b').hover(function() { $('#a').css('color','blue'); });
```

The other things you can do using just css as usual :)

Comment: Hey you answer actually work although how would i be able to do it vice versa?

Comment: @TonyThinkk you can't do using just css. because there is also no "_previous sibling_" selector available in css. you should do this dyamically using javascript or jquery.

Comment: Yeah But Its Because I dont know javascript or jquery but if i really do need that vice versa effect i guess i will use the 2nd answer thanks anyway tho your answer works like a charm

Comment: Ok Since Your Coming Up With good answer how can i use your css with another outer div? for example <div><div><ul id="a"><li></li></ul></div></div>

Comment: @TonyThinkk by opening a new question. you are just extending your requirements.... lolzz :D. that is not possible using just css.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a wrapper div, you can accomplish it without any js.
The only issue with your example is the middle `<div>` that don't have any effects applied, so the jsfiddle solution will look a tad odd, but play with the effects and it might be what you want.

The idea is that you will hover the parent and apply a style to both, then when ALSO hovering over the child, apply different styles to that child.

Also try to not use ids if possible, they restrict you more than you often need.

```
.parent:hover .list-a, .parent:hover .list-b {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}
.parent .list-a:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    background:#aaa;
}
.parent .list-b:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    background:#4c4;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tHTN4/

---

Now let's re-edit the jQuery part.  Since you don't know any jQuery, or the knowledge isn't large.  jQuery (a tool on top of Javascript) just helps you manipulate the HTML (DOM) in easy and efficient ways.  To help you not edit css in multiple places, use the addClass and removeClass functions:

```
$(function(){

    $('#a').hover(function(){
      $('#a').addClass('.list-one-effect');
      $('#b').addClass('.list-two-effect');
    }, function(){
      $('#a').removeClass('.list-one-effect');
      $('#b').removeClass('.list-two-effect');
    })
});
```

Once you remove the class, it will automatically revert to the original state (or the last altered state! from other effects).  There is also a toggleClass function in jQuery, but I'd recommend you don't use that, as the above will always tell you what state you are in when.  For completeness, this is wrapped in $(function(){}), which is one common way to make sure you have loaded jQuery AND the page is ready to run this code.

Comment: Updated your fiddle with css to achieve the above, just change the classnames to the id's you supplied.