# How To Select Multiple elements on hover

Tags: html, css

i was wondering how i cant create a multi hover on hover for example how can i make #b change colors when #a is hovered? only using html and css. by the way #a is a box or image

here's the HTML:

```
<div id="showwrap">
    <div id="leftbox">
        <ul>
            <li id="a"> <a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbox">
        <ul>
            <li id="b"> <a href="">Firstname Lastname</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be easily done with javascript, but I don't think you can do it with just css.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Yeah I Figured But Im Trying To Do It With Html And Css Lol and Plus I Dont really Know Javascript So Im Trying To Stay away From It

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/XBfPY/ - a quick javascript example

Comment: You can try wrapping your "a" in a label for "b"... that way hover a will trigger hover for "b" and your CSS will be applied to "b:hover". It may not work for non form elements.

Comment: You could use css for this if `#b` were a descendant of `#a`, but it's not

Answer (score 1):

Tony,

The same answer to the other post you had a few days ago on this subject remains the same ([How To Do Multiple Hover On List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043727/how-to-do-multiple-hover-on-list/19043817#19043817)).  It does look like there was one pure CSS answer but the jQuery options are much more simple.

Is there a reason that you are not willing / able to use jQuery or JavaScript?  That type of situation is one of the reasons JavaScript is used.  I'll keep an eye on this to hear if anyone has a pure CSS / HTML way to do this.  In the meantime, you can accomplish this with jQuery or JavaScript by the following:

1.) Create a CSS class that has the properties you want upon hovering over #a.

2.) Include the following jQuery code in the associated JavaScript file (or the head of the HTML document).

```
$(function() {
    $("#a").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hoverClass");
        $("#b").addClass("hoverClass"); 
    });
});
```

The hover function in jQuery solves both the MouseEnter and MouseOut functions in one step.  While the mouse is hovering over the specified element, the conditions inside the function are followed.  Once the mouse leaves the element, the conditions are automatically removed.  Presto!

NOTE: Although I do not recommend using inline JavaScript, this can be accomplished in the HTML file if your reason for not using jQuery is due to not having the ability to have an external JavaScript file.  Just include the snippet listed in my second point in the header between JavaScript script tags.

Comment: Yeah well I Got What I wanted On this http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/abwu8/ and when i tried coding all that in a single php file it for some reason didnt work like it did in jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you post the entire PHP code?  We might be able to help determine what's not working correctly if we see it.

Comment: no no well i tried to put all the code in to a single html file but when i added all the js fiddle code into te .html file it for some reason didnt work like when the code was generated in jsfiddle

Comment: @TonyThinkk I think you can go ahead and update your question by removing the "only using html and css" since it wasn't a real requirement. Otherwise people will come and see how you did it without js :)

Comment: @porfiriopartida No Im still looking for css html i dont want to use javascript

Comment: @Tony Thinkk - If it worked in the js fiddle it most likely has a syntax error.  If you post your complete code then we can troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only recall this behavior or a similar one using labels (if you don't want any javascript), but that will NOT work with all browsers, and the most important, you would be using HTML to do behavioral stuff and not meaning as it should be.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLtSG/

CSS

```
#b:hover, #bc:hover{
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="showwrap">
    <div id="leftbox"><label for="b"><img src="YOUR_IMAGE" /></label>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbox">
        <ul>
            <li> <input id="b" name="b" value="Firstname Lastname" /></li>
            <li> <a id="bc" name="bc">Firstname Lastname</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```