# is there a way to match several keyword in css selector?

Tags: css

```
<div class="con-one"></div>
<div class="con-two"></div>
<div class="con-three"></div>
```

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
}

[class*=-one]:hover,[class*=two]:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I want to match `.con-one` and `.con-two` like this `[class*=-one | -two]`, of course, it does not work. So could CSS selector do this point?

Comment: Did you mean to apply hover style on both classes?

Comment: Pretty sure the only way would be to use both selectors as you have it now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in CSS alone.
Check out: [How To Select Multiple elements on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103425/how-to-select-multiple-elements-on-hover)

or, you could name the classes in a way that optimizes this,

```
<div class="con-one-color"></div>
<div class="con-two-color"></div>
<div class="con-three"></div>
```

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
}

[class*=color]:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do is to use `:is()` like below:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
}

:is([class*=-one],[class*=two]):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="con-one"></div>
<div class="con-two"></div>
<div class="con-three"></div>
```